# How to stop my page from reseting after the page is submited

Tags: javascript

I have a code, who helps me switch between forms, however, when I submit the form, the page will reset and display first(default) tab again. Could anyone help me understand how I can make it so the tab I submit the form from stays there if the submision fails or even if the submision was successfull?

Forms are switching using a little JS code and are submited from a PHP POST method form.

Please find the code below:

Javascript responsible for switching between tabs:

```
function onTabClick(event) {
    let activeTabs = document.querySelectorAll('.active');
    // deactivate existing active tab
    for (let i = 0; i < activeTabs.length; i++) {
        activeTabs[i].className = activeTabs[i].className.replace('active', '');
    }

    // activate new tab
    event.target.parentElement.className += 'active';
    document.getElementById(event.target.href.split('#')[1]).className += 'active';
}

const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-tab-element');

for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener('click', onTabClick, false);
}
```

CSS:

```
.tab-content {
    display: none;
}

.tab-content.active {
    display: block;
}
```

And here is the HTML forms:

```
<body>
    <header>
        <h1 class="main-header">
            Add a New Product
        </h1>
    </header>
    <main>
        <ul id="nav-tab" class="nav">
            <li class="active">
                <a class="nav-tab-element" href="#books">Books</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="nav-tab-element" href="#dvds">DVD's</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="nav-tab-element" href="#furniture">Furniture</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <form method="POST">
            <div class="tab-content active" id="books">
                <div class="book-tab">
                    <input type="text" name="sku" placeholder="test form for books" autocomplete="off">
                </div>
                <div class="btn">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

        <form method="POST">
            <div class="tab-content " id="dvds">
                <div class="dvd-tab">
                    <input type="text" name="sku" placeholder="test form for DVD" autocomplete="off">
                </div>
                <div class="btn">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

        <form method="POST">
            <div class="tab-content " id="furniture">
                <div class="furniture-tab">
                    <input type="text" name="sku" placeholder="test form for furniture" autocomplete="off">
                </div>
                <div class="btn">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </main>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: In order to stop the page from reloading on the form submit, you will need to submit that form using ajax. That will allow you to submit your form without reloading the page and also to show success/error message to the user based on the response from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicking `submit` submits the form data to the page given in the `action` attribute in form. If you don't put this attribute in (as you have not done) the default is to submit to the current page.

To fix the issue you have, I would suggest that rather than using vanilla form submit, you do you submission via ajax. Making an ajax call is quite simple in jQuery, so I recommend you look into that.

Answer (score 0):

There is an event that is triggered when you send a form. You can prevent your page to reload doing the following:

event.preventDefault()

you can find more about here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp
or here https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp

Comment: Thank you, is it possible you tell me where you think I should place the event.preventDefault line in?

Comment: There are two ways,

or you include the onsubmit on your form tag like this:

<form onsubmit="onSubmitItems()">
  Enter name: <input type="text">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

or on onclick in your input type submit.


then you can create a function like:

function onSubmitItems(event) {
event.preventDefault()
}

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however, this stops me from submiting the form at all. Maybe you have an idea on how I can implement this, still submit the form, but after the form is submited, the selected tab is still displayed instead of the page reseting back to the first tab?

Comment: to not reload the page you need to do what I said above. To do both, send and prevent the page to reload you will need work with [Axios](https://flaviocopes.com/axios/) or [Ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp) for example.

Comment: Yes, I came to this as well unfortunately. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add event.preventDefault() to the first line of your onTabClick(event) function.  After you preventDefault you can run whatever logic you want right there.

The way vanilla html/js interact is: On form submission, the page attempts to send the info to a server and then it refreshes to update with new information.  The rise of SPAs has shifted the desired behavior, and you need to override the browser default behavior to stop the refresh.

Adding Ajax/Axios would work as most of those API libraries have built in functions to override the default, but it is not necessary.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! I tried to add the line to my code, but couldn't get it to work unfortunately. Is it possible you let me know where exactly in the JS code I should put it in? I tried to place it below and on top of activeTabs variable, but this didn't work out.